# Bash Script to Return Newest specific file extension - and then return other newer files

Tags: bash

New to scripting and trying to stitch together something.

Basically I need to find the new file in a directory with a specific extension (*.vbk), once this is found - I need to find all files with *.vib that are newer than this returned file.

I then need to copy all of these files (*.vbk and *.vib) to a mount point.

Anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: [ls -t](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) sorts by timestamp (but [don't parse ls output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)), [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) has `-newer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two find commands and so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.vbk" -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -n | awk -F\/ '{ fil=$2 } END { print fil }')" -name "*.vbk" -or -name "*.vib"
```

The first find command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.vbk" -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -n | awk -F\/ '{ fil=$2 } END { print fil }'
```

This will search for all files with the extension .vbk and in the directory and print the last modification date of the file in epoch format, followed by a "/" and then the file name. This output is then sorted and run through awk which prints only the last file name.

The output of this is then used as a reference file for the find -newer flag to find .vbk or .vib files

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this. I will study what you have given me and try to understand how it hangs together. WIll run it against some sample files and see how we go.

Comment: Hey Raman, just a follow up - started playing with this yesterday on different folders - it almost what i want (and i spent a few hours trying to break it down) but not quite there yet. Instead of returning just the latest *.vbk file (i.e. the newest) it appears to return all *.vbk files. It then returns all *.vib files as they are newer.